# Counterclockwise and clockwise rotation and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time with this problem and am hoping to see if someone can provide some guidance.

Compute the matrices of a counter clockwise rotation by an angle theta and the clockwise rotation by the same angle. Multiply them together in both possible orders.

Also, a followup question asks what we can conclude from the answer and how it relates to geometric considerations about a 2D plane. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To start with, remember that a matrix represents a linear transformation when a coordinate system is chosen; you may have heard this referred to as 'with respect to a given basis'.

So first off, what is a linear transformation?
It's nothing more than a function on a vector space that happens to be linear.
Meaning $T:V\to V$ is linear if
$$T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha T(x)+\beta T(y)$$
for every $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$ and every $x,y\in V$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field the vector space is defined over.

So anyway, in your case the vector space would be the 2D plane and the field would be $\mathbb{R}$ the real number system.

So first, check that rotation about the origin by some angle is in fact a linear transformation.

Now what does matrix multiplication really mean?

Since a matrix represents the action of a function on a vector space, if I have two matricies they represent two functions and when we multiply them this corresponds to function composition.

With this in mind, if I rotate about the origin by some angle, and then rotation again by the negative of that angle (counterclockwise/clockwise) the net effect should be nothing.

What matrix represents the transformation that does nothing?

Hope this helps.